# How do I mock a backend in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, testing, angularjs, mocking

My angular app communicates with my server through a REST API. I want to mock out this API to quickly develop the front end.

There are two approaches I see:

1. Use [ngMockE2E $httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend). This requires:

   - spinning up a simple static file server (e.g. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`)
   - Load angular-mocks.js in my client
   - Configure the mock `$httpBackend` to return what I want.

   Downsides: Have to have client side logic that determines whether to use the mock backend or not. Also, doesn't mock actual $httpRequests and we might get confused with all the flush() calls.
2. Create an actual mock backend. E.g. spin up a very basic node.js server that will respond to *actual* xhr requests.

   Downsides: ?

ngMockE2e $httpBackend seems to be what others are using, but I'm not sure why. Having a real (mock) backend seems more straightforward and less likely to cause errors while developing.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `.json` file right next to your `index.html`. Make your `$http` request to fetch this json file which contains the data your backend returns. This is the easiest way to mock your backend. Ofcourse, I am assuming that you are serving your angular app through a web server. If you are not already running a web server then this solution wont work.

In production you could just replace the url for this json file with the actual REST end point.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't let me test different types of responses (403, 502, etc.).

Comment: can you provide an example ?!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I started with a simple .json file as suggested by ganaraj but moved on to a simple node.js server when I needed to test data modification.

The ngMockE2e is really used for testing and not designed for actually serving as a RESTful server.  In the example from the link you provided, if you were to run a GET for a specific phone, you would have to loop through the phones array to find the one needed.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350681/how-can-i-create-a-mock-back-end-in-angular/20350682#20350682).

Basically you include angular-mocks after angular, and use the code provided in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kennethlynne/7767088)
and you will be able to controll both requests and responses, including headers and fake response delays etc.

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative more automated way of backend mocking, take a look at [swagger-api-mock](https://github.com/bulkismaslom/swagger-api-mock) that works just great together with [rest-json](https://github.com/bulkismaslom/rest-json). 
These modules together can be used to generate $httpBackend responses: rest-json.js as http-like access to json data and swagger-api-mock/lib/mock-data.js as generator for the json mock data objects based on swagger (or json schema) definitions